# the performance of erlang numeric calculation

Tags: erlang

**C version:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned int test(unsigned int n_count) {
  unsigned int c = 1;
  unsigned int i;
  for (i=0; i< n_count;i++) {
    c += 2 * 34 + 1;
    c /= 2;
    c *= 39;
  }
  return c;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  printf("%u\n", test(atoi(argv[1])));
}
```

Result:

```
$ gcc p2.c
$ time ./a.out 100000000
563970997

real    0m0.865s
user    0m0.864s
sys 0m0.004s
```

**erlang version:**

```
-module(test2).
-export([main/1]).
-mode(compile).
calc(Cnt, Total) when Cnt > 0 ->
  if Total >= 4294967296 -> Total2 = Total rem 4294967296;
    true -> Total2 = Total end,
  calc(Cnt - 1, trunc((Total2 + 2 * 34 + 1) / 2) * 39);
calc(0, Total)->
  if Total >= 4294967296 -> Total2 = Total rem 4294967296;
    true -> Total2 = Total end,
  io:format("~p ~n", [Total2]),
  ok.
main([A])->
  Cnt = list_to_integer(A),
  calc(Cnt, 1).
```

Result:

```
$ erlc +native +"{hipe, [to_llvm]}" test2.erl
$ time escript test2.beam 100000000
563970997 

real    0m4.940s
user    0m4.892s
sys 0m0.056s
$ erlc +native test2.erl
$ time escript test2.beam 100000000
563970997 

real    0m5.381s
user    0m5.320s
sys 0m0.064s
$ erlc test2.erl
$ time escript test2.beam 100000000
563970997 

real    0m9.868s
user    0m9.808s
sys 0m0.056s
```

How to improve the performance of erlang version?
In erlang, I have to simulate the integer overflow case, is there better way?
And even with hipe, the performance is far from C.

**Edit:**

**Python version:**

```
def test(n_count):
    c = 1
    for i in xrange(n_count):
        c += 2 * 34 + 1
        c /= 2
        c *= 39
        if c >= 4294967296:
          c = c % 4294967296
    return c
print test(100000000)
```

Result:

```
$ time python p2.py
563970997

real    0m17.813s
user    0m17.808s
sys 0m0.008s
$ time pypy p2.py
563970997

real    0m1.852s
user    0m0.508s
sys 0m0.128s
```

Comment: Erlang is not very good at number-crunching. You could implement your arithmetic-modules in C, and use it via port-drivers / NIFs.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by  *integer overflow case*? Erlang uses BigNum for integers, so they don't flow over...

Comment: you probably want to exclude VM startup time measurement from your test, b/c it is somehow slow. But anyway as have been mentioned, erlang is bad in number crunching.

Comment: Erlang has a virtual machine which needs to load before your actual program runs. Even with the escript, that machine has to be ready to execute your program. This is not present in C.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link may be especially helpful, you'll be able to 'bake' your C code into your Erlang application:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html

Answer (score 0):

Erlang really has not good in digit-rolling tasks. It good, if you want take bytes and send them. 
Usual serious Erlang development cycle is including final optimization, when you rewriting some bottleneck modules to native. 
Yes, Erlang looks like good calc (and projects like Wings3D showing that), but maybe you must choose another tool?